# How to query a clause for solr java client?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am now using solr to query .I want to find all the documents whose key "title" contains text "Bifidobacterium bifidum" or key "abstract" contains text "Bifidobacterium bifidum".So , I write my query like below:

```
String queryCondition = "title:*Bifidobacterium bifidum* OR  abstract:*Bifidobacterium bifidum*";
```

From the result ,I find out that the returned result is not what I want ,documents whose title contains "Bifidobacterium" or "bifidum" , or whose title contains "Bifidobacterium" or "bifidum" are all returned . So , my question is ,how should I write my query to satisfy my query need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` is special symbol, a wildcard. Similar to regular expressions, it tells Solr to match **everything**. So querying for `bifidum*` would return everything that starts with bifidum. Not what you want, right?

When reading about [Solr's query syntax in the manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser), you will find a section named **Specifying Terms for the Standard Query Parser** there is written

> A phrase is a group of words surrounded by double quotes such as "hello dolly"

This is what you need ...

Comment: This is definitely what I want.Thank you.